# HTML PHP entering entry to table in different rows

Tags: php, html

I am working on a project and I got a small problem.I want to display a request to an owner which is stored in a table in mySQL.The first entry is fine.But the second entry comes next to the first entry instead of below.So it seems like this
Header Header Header Header
value   value  value  value     2ndvalue 2ndvalue 2ndvalue 2ndvalue.
How can I fix this and put the 2nd values below the respective headers and value.Here is my code

```
<table border='1' cellpadding='5'>"
    <title>View Incoming Orders</title>
    <tr> <th>Restaurant Name</th>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Order Date</th>
    <th>Details</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>is Processed</th>
    <th> Finalize Order </th>
    <th> Delete </th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php
        $length=count($restaurantNames);
            for($c=0; $c<$length; $c++){
            $custDate=$customers[$c]. "/".$orderDates[$c];
            echo "<td> $restaurantNames[$c]</td>";
            echo "<td> $customers[$c]</td>";
            echo "<td> $orderDates[$c]</td>";
            echo "<td> $detailss[$c]</td>";
            echo "<td> $costs[$c]</td>";
            echo "<td> $isProcesseds[$c]</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox'  name='check_list[]' value='$custDate' />Finalize Order </td>";
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox'  name='check_list2[]' value='$custDate' />Delete </td>";

            }

        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr><input type="submit" id="update" name="update" value="Update"></input></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try moving your `tr` into the loop instead of outside of it. Also `title` is not valid for how you are using it. It is meant for the title tag of the website in `head`

```
<table border='1' cellpadding='5'>"
    <title>View Incoming Orders</title>
    <tr> <th>Restaurant Name</th>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Order Date</th>
    <th>Details</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>is Processed</th>
    <th> Finalize Order </th>
    <th> Delete </th>

    </tr>
    <?php
        $length=count($restaurantNames);
            for($c=0; $c<$length; $c++){
echo "<tr>";
            $custDate=$customers[$c]. "/".$orderDates[$c];
            echo "<td> $restaurantNames[$c]</td>";
            echo "<td> $customers[$c]</td>";
            echo "<td> $orderDates[$c]</td>";
            echo "<td> $detailss[$c]</td>";
            echo "<td> $costs[$c]</td>";
            echo "<td> $isProcesseds[$c]</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox'  name='check_list[]' value='$custDate' />Finalize Order </td>";
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox'  name='check_list2[]' value='$custDate' />Delete </td>";
echo "</tr>";
            }

        ?>

    <tr><input type="submit" id="update" name="update" value="Update"></input></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: This works.I am accepting it as an answer.But I think title  can work like that since it is working in the site I am managing